# Sort Array based on multiple values

Tags: php, arrays

I need to sort an array of objects based on the objects properties. Basically if you take a look at [this](http://developers.fifteendigital.co.uk/tests/example/) fixture table and note "Liverpool FC" and "Manchester City FC" you can see that they have the same amount of points, so they are ordered based on the other values being higher.

Now if you take a look at [mine](http://developers.fifteendigital.co.uk/tests/8gys2/) i'm only ordering based on the points, i'm not sure how to order this based on multiple values.

The data is stored within an instance of a class, this instance is stored within an `Array(`) with the `Key` being the team name.

Below is the class which managed the data, how can I re-arrange the array so that the objects are in order the way the first link has them ordered?

```
 class Calc {
    private $config;
    public $win = 0, $draw = 0, $loss = 0, $goalFor = 0, $goalConc = 0;

    public function __construct($payload = array(0,0)) {
      // Load config file
      $this->config = parse_ini_file('config.ini', true);

      // Add wins, losses, draws, goals for and goal conceived
      $this->addData($payload);
    }

    // Linked data updated, ammend values
    public function calcPlays() {
      return 0 + $this->win + $this->draw + $this->loss;
    }
    public function calcPoints() {
      // Add 0 to ensure value is an int
      return $this->win * ($this->config['winPoints']) + ($this->draw * $this->config['drawPoints']) + ($this->loss * $this->config['lossPoints']);
    }
    public function calcGoalDifference() {
      return ($this->goalFor - $this->goalConc);
    }

    public function addData($data) {
      // Append goal data
      $this->goalFor += $data[0];
      $this->goalConc += $data[1];

      // Win, Loss or Draw
      if ($data[0] > $data[1]) { $this->win++;} elseif
      ($data[0] < $data[1]) { $this->loss++;} elseif
      ($data[0] == $data[1]) { $this->draw++;}
    }
  }
```

**Edit:**

My data is now everywhere:

```
1   Burnley FC  13  4   2   7   12  21  -9  14
2   Leicester City FC   13  3   4   6   16  22  -6  13
3   Crystal Palace FC   13  3   2   8   21  26  -5  11
4   Swansea City FC 13  2   3   8   16  26  -10 9
5   Arsenal FC  13  8   4   1   28  13  15  28
```

I'm assuming my checks are the wrong way around, I was assuming it would check if `$a` is bigger than or equal to `$b`, if so then return true, if not move on to the next check?

The code:

```
// Sort teams by points
uasort($teamData, function($a, $b) {
  if ($a->calcPoints() < $b->calcPoints() && $a->calcPoints() !== $b->calcPoints()) {
    return true;
  } elseif ($a->calcGoalDifference() < $b->calcGoalDifference() && $a->calcGoalDifference() !== $b->calcGoalDifference()) {
    return true;
  } elseif($a->goalConc < $b->goalConc) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and write a function that compares the different values and sorts them accordingly.

Something along the lines of:

```
uasort($teamData, function ($a, $b)
{
    if ( $a->calcPoints() < $b->calcPoints() )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    elseif ( $a->calcPoints() <= $b->calcPoints() && $a->calcGoalDifference() < $b->calcGoalDifference() )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    elseif ( ($a->calcPoints() <= $b->calcPoints() && $a->calcGoalDifference() <= $b->calcGoalDifference()) && $a->goalConc < $b->goalConc )
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});
```

Comment: You got any idea how football premier league positions are calculated as I don't know football at all!

Comment: Nope, I know very little about football but my guess is first Pts, then GD, then A

Comment: I adjusted to match your needs, I think

Comment: FYI: @trincot's post is a clean approach then mine.

Answer (score 2):

Use `usort` as follows:

```
uasort($teamData, function($a, $b) {
    $diff = $a->calcPoints() - $b->calcPoints();
    if (!$diff) $diff = $a->calcGoalDifference() - $b->calcGoalDifference();
    if (!$diff) $diff = $a->goalConc - $b->goalConc;
    return $diff;
});
```

The `if` conditions are true when the previous comparison was a tie. Note also that the return value is *not* supposed to be a boolean, but a signed number.

This sorts in ascending order. If you need it the other way around, then swap the positions of *$a* and *$b* either in the argument list, or in the expressions.